# A function possible inputs in PYTHON

Tags: python, function, input, jupyter-notebook

How can I quickly check what are the possible inputs to a specific function? For example, I want to plot a histogram for a data frame: `df.hist()`. I know I can change the bin size, so I know probably there is a way to give the desired bin size as an input to the hist() function. If instead of `bins = 10` I use `df.hist(bin = 10)`, Python obviously gives me an error and says hist does not have property **bin**.

I wonder how I can quickly check what are the possible inputs to a function.

Comment: Generally, you need to read the documentation.

Comment: An editor or IDE with decent completion can help too.

Comment: I know the best way is always reading the documentation but sometimes, like the example I described above, you have a good guess of what the input should look like and I was looking for a way to verify quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to see if there is documentation on the function itself:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
help(DF.hist)
```

Alternatively, if you are inside IPython, using `DF.hist?` will work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question tag contains jupyter notebook I am assuming you are trying on it. So in jupyter notebook 2.0 `Shift+Tab` would give you function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the help function:

```
help(df.hist)
```

Also:

```py
df.hist? # in ipython only
```

The possible arguments will print into the console.

Comment: The `?` suffix syntax isn't part of Python. It's something that `iPython` adds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inspect` module

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y

print(inspect.signature(f))
```

See the documentation of the module for details regarding the returned type.